# How does this subquery work?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select max(salary) 
from employee 
WHERE salary NOT IN (select MAX(salary) from employee)
```

The query above returns 2nd highest salary. Now I know there are other ways to find 2nd highest salary but I can't understand how the above query is working. This might be very easy but could someone please break it down so that it is understandable.

Comment: You need to understand the order in which SQL executes.  in this case, the where clause executes against the set of records in the employee table eliminating the employee with the highest salary from the dataset the engine is working with (a subset of employee now excluding the highest paid).  Then the select executes returning the employee with the highest salary left in the set.

Comment: @xQbert I think it's not so obvious. Using this technique, what's the *next* highest salary?

Comment: @strawberry That's not the question. "Please break it down so that it is understandable" not how do I get the 3rd highest.  The question even states, he knows there are other ways to find it, but this specific example is what the OP trying to understand

Comment: @Strawberry +1 for understanding the question exactly as it was written :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'Where' conditions are execute before aggregate function**

For more clearification
   Here in employee table has salary like 10000,15000,20000

FIRST `WHERE salary NOT IN (select MAX(salary) from employee) =20000` GET Execute  and
value `20000` stored for comparision

THEN IT CHECK one by one from  MAX value LIKE  `20000 != 20000` false

THEN CHECK other MAX value `15000 != 20000`  true

so 15000 will return

To know more about SQL execution order see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a potentially very slow and complex query which does the same as this one:

```
SELECT salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC limit 1,1
```

Your subquery finds the highest salary, then you are doing an outer query to find all the salaries that are not the higest salaries and then taking it's max.

Find highest

```
select MAX(salary) from employee
```

Find salaries that are not highest as follows:

```
WHERE NOT IN (select MAX(salary) from employee)
```

find maximum salary which is not the highest!!

select max(salary)  ....

Comment: If two or more people tie on the highest salary, the two queries are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the order in which SQL executes. In this case, the where clause executes against the set of records in the employee table eliminating the employee with the highest salary from the dataset the engine is working with (a subset of employee now excluding the highest paid). Then the select executes returning the employee with the highest salary left in the set.

```
John    45,000
Paul    26,000
George  87,000
Ringo   33,000
```

So the engine identifies George as having 87,000 the highest
and eliminates it from the data set  (note: All indivduals having this max salary are excluded not just 1 so as Linkan points out, if Brian has a salary of 87,000 it too would be eliminated) ... leaving the following in memory.

Thus the where clause
`WHERE salary NOT IN (select MAX(salary) from employee)` has done its job.

```
John    45,000
Paul    26,000
Ringo   33,000
```

The engine then looks through and finds John is now the highest (max) in the reamining set, and thus eliminates the other 2 and returns:
and the select completes it's job: `select max(salary)`

```
45,000
```

So the order in which the SQL executes is generalized as:

1. FROM
2. JOINS
3. WHERE
4. GROUP BY
5. HAVING
6. SELECT
7. ORDER BY

Comment: If say Brian also has 87,000 in salary, the query will still choose 45,000. This is because it excluded everybody with the highest salary.

Answer (score 0):

Say employee has below records

```
EmpId Salary

1     50000
2     40000
3     35000
4     30000
5     25000
6     20000
```

The sub-query in where clause returns the below result which is

```
Max(Salary)
50000
```

Then in the where clause you have used `Salary NOT IN (select MAX(salary) from employee)` which implies `Salary NOT IN (50000)`, which will give you the result

```
Max(Salary)
40000
```

Hence the result is the second largest value.